How to uninstall php from macOS 10.15 and after that install latest version of php 8.2
In my mac php already installed. when i checking php version help of terminal by command 'php -v' it showing php@7.3 but at 'http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php' php version showing php@8.2.4
I tried uninstall php help of terminal with brew command but but it's showing error 'Error: No available formula with the name "php@7.3.29". Did you mean php@8.2?' after that i tried with 'brew uninstall php@8.2' and it's showing 'Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.2'

As far as I know, the PHP version detected in the phpinfo.php file is the version used by Apache. Perhaps the 7.3 version that appears in the terminal is the PHP for CLI.
